# Converting a JFrame to a JApplet

Tags: java, deployment, applet, jframe, japplet

I have a JFrame application working nicely. However now I'd like to run it on the web as an Applet. This is what I've done:

```
import MyPackage.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyName extends JApplet
{

     public void init() {
        setSize(600,450);
        new MyName()
     }

    public MyName() {
        JShellFrame frame = new JShellFrame(true, null, null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

How can I make an html file to run this applet? Also, I have an external jar file that the applet will need. Does the applet not need a main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Getting Started With Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html). It covers relevant [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletMethods.html) and [life cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html). It mentions `main` method as well:

> Unlike Java applications, applets do not need to implement a main
>   method.

[Deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) section covers HTML file details. For dependency jars you can specify more than one jar in `archive` attribute of `applet` tag.

Answer (score 1):

> However now I'd like to run it on the web..

Then drop this nonsense and launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  I say 'nonsense' for two reasons.

1. JWS has existed since Java 1.2, & has been discussed in these forums several times in the last few days in regard to applets.  Seems you are not doing much research.
2. Of the 'gargantuan' 2 lines of applet code code shown above, one of them is ill-advised and the other is either pointless or would risk creating a stack overflow error (could not be bothered trying it to find out which).

Answer (score 0):

here's some html that will work:

`<applet archive = "appName.jar" width = 900 height = 506 code = "main.class"/>`

You can change the width and height according to the size your app needs. Also make sure to put the url as a path to the jar.