# how to display jFrame Form in a Java web application (NetBeans)

Tags: java, html, web-applications, netbeans

I have finished the application in NetBeans (`Gume.java`, consists of only one jFrame Form), all that needs to be done, is to implement it to HTML document (`index.html`). How can it be done?

Data structure:

[image: Data structure]

Comment: You need to replace Swing components with HTML components or you need to use Applet - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html

Comment: Could you show me, how to use Applet in this particular case?

Comment: Worked long back on it. But something like this - <applet archive = "Gume.jar" width = 900 height = 506 code = "Gume.class"/>

Comment: you need to convert JFrame to Applet first - please take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059885/converting-a-jframe-to-a-japplet

Answer (score 1):

Solved: just add a new jApplet Form (right click on project/ New/ Other/ AWR GUI Forms/ Applet Form) and copy the jFrame Form elements to the jApplet Form.