# Converting JFrame code to JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet

So I'm honestly not too sure how to use applets, but my code: http://pastebin.com/rV9KqsV7

How do I convert my JFrame code into JApplet?

Comment: dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059885/converting-a-jframe-to-a-japplet

Comment: get started to convert it. [Learn more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html)