# From JFrame application to Applet

Tags: java, html, applet

I am trying to modify a JFrame application to an applet. The jframe application can run in eclipse well. But I don't know how to make an applet class and how to compile it so that it can be used in the HTML codes.
Now the JFrame application contains a main method.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10060135/1144203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inherit from `java.applet.Applet`. Create a file named `MyClass.java` and write an applet like this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;



public class MyClass extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {

        // Probably your constructor code here.
        // Or rather create a separate constructor for MyClass 
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

Compile the code as:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

Now create an `html` file and save it by the name `MyApp.html` like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <applet code="MyClass.class" width=500 height=500>
            Any message to be printed if browsers do not support applets.
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open the `html` document in a browser.

Nowadays browsers don't support unsigned applets. So I suggest you to hit the command line and type:

```
appletviewer MyApp.html
```

and view your applet in an appletviewer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I am facing a problem that I tried to make multiple class files into a jar file, and try to code this Applet.jar in html5. What can I do?

Comment: Yo here you go. This is a nice tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/index.html

Comment: I can view my applet in the appletviewer but when I try to load the webpage, it says classnotfoundexception, and then the name of my applet class.

Comment: Yes. I have multiple classes and I use Eclipse to export a jar file. So now I have those compiled class files and one jar file. Where Should I put these files? The same as the html file right? Only the jar file or everything? Thank you!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/11561669/class-not-found-in-my-jar-file

Comment: check this link out.